# How to reuse this JavaScript code passing different C# variables as parameters?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, code-reuse

I need to reuse a JavaScript code that draws a pieChart in an HTML Page with Razor. Now I'm only passng a single DataTable to the view to be rendered as the pieChart, but I want to pass 3 more DataTables without having to repeat 3 times the JavaScript Code.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
        {
            var data = db.SomeDatabaseTable;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Title").DataType = typeof(string);
            dt.Columns.Add("Value").DataType = typeof(int);

            DataRow firstRow = dt.NewRow();
            DataRow secndRow = dt.NewRow();
            DataRow thirdRow = dt.NewRow();

            firstRow[0] = "Invalid Mails";
            secndRow[0] = "Null Mails";
            thirdRow[0] = "Valid Mails";

            firstRow[1] = data.Where(Some Contition).Count();
            secndRow[1] = data.Where(Other Condition).Count();
            thirdRow[1] = data.Where(An Other Condition).Count();

            dt.Rows.Add(firstRow);
            dt.Rows.Add(secndRow);
            dt.Rows.Add(thirdRow);

            ViewBag.data = dt;

            return View();
        }
```

As you all can see, I'm passing the DataTable filled with the willing Values as teh variable "data" in the ViewBag. Then, in the View, I fill the Javascript code using a foreach throught the datatable (ViewBag.data) i've passed, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
            @{int count = 0;}
            @foreach (DataRow row in ((DataTable)ViewBag.data).Rows)
                {
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        @Html.Raw(",['" + row[0] + "'," + row[1] +"]");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.Raw("['" + row[0] + "'," + row[1] +"]");
                    }
                count++;
                }
        ]);

        var options = {
            'title': 'Title',
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Then, this visualization is trendered in the 'char_div' div that i have in my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>DashBoard</h1>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div id="chart_div"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**So... the question is:
¿There is a clean way to pass the total of 4 dataTables to the View And render 4 pieCharts respectively without having to repeat the JavaScript code 4 times?.**

I guess that i've to loop inside the JavaScript 1 time for each dataTable I want to render, but i don't know how to tho it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Using a DataTable is the worst thing you could use. Create a view model containing the properties you want (`string Name`, `int Value`) and create a collection of that view model for each pie chart. Then pass a model to the view (not `ViewBag`(and serialize it to a javascript array, so you can use a simple loop to get the values for each pie chart and pass it to function that draws the chart.

Comment: You can use `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode()` to convert a C# ViewModel to JSON data you can iterate over in your JS code.